# how to convert and update japanese date format into real datetime format in mysql

Tags: mysql

i have field feel with japanese date format like down below

```
+------------+
| post_date  |
+------------+
| 2020年2月1  |
| 2020年2月3  |
| 2020年2月11 |
| 2020年2月15 |
| 2020年2月20 |
| 2020年2月27 |
+------------+
```

how do i can change this field into real datetime `2020年2月1` become `2020-02-01 00:00:00` and update it in same or different field

what i already trid is like this

try 1 :

```
UPDATE `table` SET `post_date` = str_to_date( `post_date`, '%Y-%m-%d %h%i%s' );
```

try 2 :

```
UPDATE `table` SET `post_date` = date_format(str_to_date( `post_date`, '%Y年%m月%d' ), '%Y-%m-%d %h%i%s');
```

but non of that is working. please help

Comment: what was the error of the second?

Answer (score 0):

You were missing the `:` between hours-minutes-seconds, this:

```
SELECT date_format(str_to_date( '2020年2月27', '%Y年%m月%d' ), '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s');
```

returns:

```
2020-02-27 12:00:00
```

If you want the time to be `00:00:00`, you can manually type it:

```
SELECT date_format(str_to_date( '2020年2月27', '%Y年%m月%d' ), '%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00');
```

So at the end it should be:

```
UPDATE `table` SET `post_date` = date_format(str_to_date( `post_date`, '%Y年%m月%d' ), '%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00');
```

Comment: Seeing as you made a data set, why not share it?

Comment: @Strawberry sorry, which set of data are you referring to?

Comment: My mistake, I guess.